# inputmask must allow unlimited digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

So below is my snippet, currently inputmask allow only this format "_.**" (e.g 5.55). Is there a way I could extend the format like I want this format "**._____________.." (e.g 55.555555555555555555555... where after 55. the rest of the input digits must be unlimited). Any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.decimal').inputmask({ mask: "*[.**]", greedy: false, definitions: { '*': { validator: "[0-9]" } } });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="decimal form-control" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.decimal').inputmask({ mask: "99.9{1,}"})
```

`{1,}` = `minimum 1 , infinite` for the preceding char , if you need it optional `{0,}`

Comment: I know it is been a while, but is there a way to accomplish the same result but using something like "{1,}9.99"

Comment: i think u mean `"9{1,2}.99"` so you can get : 2.95 or 23.95

Comment: that worked! Thanks, is there any way I can set it to accept both dots (.) and commas (,)?

Comment: `(9{1,2}.99)|(9{1,2},99)` should do the trick , i did not test it ... i am a little far from inputmask itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Inputmask("*{n}").mask($(".text_only"));
```

Here n stands for n number

Comment: thanks it works, I used it in alphanumeric mask like this :


`$('.alphaNumeric_mask').inputmask('*{Z}',{ "placeholder": "", translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, recursive: false}}});`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question but in my case **I wanted unlimited integers**, so I used the expression:

`9{0,}`